# pip says it is out of date but updating says it is the latest version!

Tags: python, pip, amazon-linux

If I try and do the following:

```
pip --version
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3049, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3033, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3062, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 660, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 673, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Which looks as if pip is out of date so I try and do this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I get this:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (10.0.1)
```

So I am confused! How can I get pip to the version pip seems to need to require?

More information on installation, whereis tells me that pip is available here:

```
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
```

and python:

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Comment: You have two Python installations, one in `/usr` and one in `/usr/local`. Without knowing more about your Python setup and what your `PATH` and `PYTHONHOME`/`PYTHONPATH` variables are, it's difficult to know how to answer this properly.

Comment: @Kusalananda ok what information can I add to help aid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kusalananda said there were multiple versions of pip in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin. I solved this by creating a symbolic link from /usr/bin to the version in /usr/local/bin which is the latest version:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use a symbolic link or install the application with the latest pip version in `/usr/local/bin/`